# Julia - Parallelizing an animate loop

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, plots.jl

I want to make an `@animate for` loop work in parallel, usually when I work with parallel I use `(@sync )@parallel for`, but it won't work for an animate loop as both macros try to detect the `for` keyword after. So is there a way to do it with just macros ?

Comment: Why not use a function that produces data using `@parallel` and a `@animate for` loop that calls that function?

Comment: I found that in the case of my code, the thing that eats all the CPU is the plotting function ( a heatmap in my case ) and not the data production itself.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to filter data before plotting it. Can you provide sample code using random data?